# Is there a way in Java to be notified when a select object's data changes?

Tags: java, swing

I have a DefaultListSelectionModel and I'm registering via addListSelectionListener. This tells me when a new row gets selected, is there any way to be notified when a selected row's data changes (or maybe even gets repainted)?

Comment: PropertyChageListeners *could* help, but the devil's in the details of your application and classes. Your question seems to me to be a bit broad as currently written.

Comment: Google Java Observer and Observable : for article like [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)

Comment: That depends on so many different things.  The underlying model might provide some help, but that will also depend on how you data is been modified and how it is managed

Comment: You wouldn't want to know every time it gets repainted, it happens so often, and it is pointless anyway. The value change can be detected by a ListDataListener on the ListModel, but the only way its value can change is if you change it: why do you need to be told what you own code is doing?